# Quest for the king meaning

Tags: meaning

Consider this book title: "Prince vs Prince - Quest for the king"

Does "quest for the king" here mean that they're "searching" for the king (like maybe he is missing or something) or it could also mean that the king has send them on a quest, that it's a quest on behalf of the king, like "Go get this land/castle for me"?

Comment: I suspect it should say "Quest for the Kingship".  The princes are vying against each other. "vs" = *versus*.

Comment: @TRomano, so you would say that as it is it has no clear meaning?

Comment: I suspect ""king" is the wrong word, judging from what little evidence there is.  In any event, its meaning is unclear.  I would not say that the ambiguity is intentional. I think it is simply a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is unclear - either of your interpretations is possible.

Bear in mind that this is likely deliberate. It's not unusual for book titles to be deliberately ambiguous or to have multiple meanings or interpretations.

The biggest source of ambiguity is the use of the word "Quest". This is both archaic and non specific - a quest can be any mission or goal one seeks to achieve, normally involving a journey somewhere. So to make the meaning clearer, we should probably replace Quest with something more precise:

> Prince vs Prince: **Hunt** for the King

This would imply that the princes are seeking the missing King.

> ...**Mission** for the King
>   ...**Command** of the King
>   ...**In Service** of the King

These all maintain the ambiguity about exactly what task has to be performed, but makes it clearer that it's a task that's been assigned by the king.

> ...Quest for the **Throne**

By replacing **King** with **Throne**, it becomes clear that the Princes are competing with one another to become king themselves.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Are there any alternatives that would fit those meanings better? I'm particularly interested in the second interpretation.

Comment: My pleasure - I edited the answer to include some example alternatives.